# how to hide column in django form and set foreign key value

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I want to hide the column bh in the html page so I am hiding it by exclude in forms.py and trying to set foreign key column bh with request.user.username in the views but it is giving me this error:
Cannot assign "]>": "Bed.bh" must be a "Hospital" instance.

Is there any way to resolve the issue. Please help!

```
`#forms.py

class BedForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Bed
    fields = ('bed_id','bed_type','created_date','bh',)
    exclude=('bh',)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = BedForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            bed = form.save(commit=False)
            bed.created_date = timezone.now()
            hh = Hospital.objects.filter(hospital_id=request.user.username)
            bed.bh=hh
            bed.save()
            b = Bed.objects.filter(bh=request.user.username)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Hospital.objects.filter()` is returning a `QuerySet`, not an instance of `Hospital`.

You want something like:

```
hh = Hospital.objects.filter(hospital_id=request.user.username)[0]
```

or

```
hh = Hospital.objects.get(hospital_id=request.user.username)
```

In both cases, however you will have to either check that the object exists before retrieving it, or catch the exception, then figure out what to do next.